# How to use Small Talk

Tags: dialogflow-es, node-red, facebook-chatbot

I enable Small Talk but when I asked the Bot questions It does not return any value. I Using node-red chat bot. Thank so much

[image: Terminal show status server node-red]

[image: When i ask my bot "Who are you?" in about agent]

Comment: did you test the small talks in the Dialogflow's try it now?

Comment: Yeahhh, it's really run. But when i use API - not working T.T. Thanks for support

Comment: can you post the logs from the Dialogflow? The request and response. You can enable it in the settings.

Comment: can you show us your small talk dialogflow GUI as well...

Comment: Click here: https://ibb.co/gcU5Yd . Thanks you

Comment: can you show us your webhook code as well

Comment: Sorry i don't use webhook. I used node-red server